# Why do we need web servers if we have load balancer to direct the requests?

Tags: apache, webserver, load-balancing, distributed-computing, distributed-system

Suppose we have two servers serving requests through a load balancer. Is it necessary to have web server in both of our servers to process the requests. Can load balancer itself act as a web server. Suppose we are using apache web server and HAProxy. So does that mean that web server(Apache) should be installed in both the server and load balancer in any one of the server. Why can't we have load balancer in both of our server machine that will be receiving the request and talking to each other to process the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load balancer is in front of your webserver(s) to redirect requests according to number of sessions, a hash of source IP and destination IP, requested URL or other criteria. Additionally, it will check availability of the backend servers to ensure requests get answered even if one server fails.

It's not installed on every webserver - you only need one instance. It could be a hardware appliance, or a software (like HAproxy) which may or may not be installed on one of the webservers. Although this would not be prudent, as this webserver could fail and then the proxy would not be able to redirect traffic to the remaining server.

There are several different scenarios for this. One is load balancing requests to 2 webservers which serve the same HTML content, to provide redundancy.

Another would be to provide multiple websites using just one public address, i.e. applying destination NAT according to the requested URL. For this, the software has to determine the URL in the HTML request and redirect traffic to the backend webserver servicing this site. This sometimes is called 'reverse proxy' as it hides the internal server addresses from the outside.

Comment: so apache web server should be installed in all of our server machines right?

Comment: when we had single machine it was the apache web server which used  to receive server request, now since we have load balancer the request will be very first received by the load balancer and then it will forward it to any one of our apache web servers.Am I right?

Comment: both comments: YES. Redundancy/load balancing  can only be achieved with (at least) 2 identical servers. Note that the servers do not need public IP addresses anymore - requests to your URL point at the balancer.

Answer (score 3):

At the very basic, you want to have Webservers fulfill requests for static contents, while Application servers handle business logics, i.e. handle requests for dynamic contents.

But Web servers can do many other things as well such as authenticate and validate requests, logging metrics. Also, the important part of Webserver is putting the Content it gets from Application servers with a View for client to represent.

You want to have LB sitting in front of both Web and App servers if you have more than one server. Also, there's nothing preventing you from putting both Web and App server in one.